# HttpResponse does not contain a definition for BinaryWrite() in Dot Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, httpresponse

I am new in Asp .Net core.

what is `BinaryWrite()` method for `httpResponse` in .NetCore ?

Also I need `Flush()` and `End()` in .NetCore But I can't find it.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but the new approach is likely to be using `HttpResponse.Body` and its `WriteAsync`, `FlushAsync`, etc.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for response it was usefull , but what about End() ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194200/how-httpcontext-response-end-in-asp-net-core

Comment: OK , but can we use `Response.Body.DisposeAsync()` or `Response.Body.close()`?

Comment: You shouldn't really need to "end" the response explicitly - I suggest adding more information about what the original code is doing here so a suitable suggestion can be made.

Comment: In brief : I want to submit a byte array (or file) to client.

Answer (score 3):

You likely need [SendFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sendfileresponseextensions.sendfileasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_SendFileResponseExtensions_SendFileAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponse_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) you might need to install another nuget package to get it [Microsoft.AspNetCore.http.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/)

For example:

```
response.SendFileAsync(fileNameFullPath);
```